# How to fix a "Read Only" hard drive issue when trying to install Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, 13.04, hard-drive

so I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop and currently have it mounted on a flash drive. When I select the "Install Ubuntu" program, it fails saying that my hard drive is read-only. How do I make it so that it is not read-only from inside Ubuntu? Also, I am a complete noob with Ubuntu so I have to be guided step by step. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be that my hard drive was broken. I got a new one and it is fine. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Open up terminal and install this package:

```
    sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

Then, under the GNOME Menu (in the top left, look through the second sub menu from the bottom) click NTFS-3G and set this up.

Take a look at this for reference:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions?action=show&redirect=MountingWindowsPartitions%2FThirdPartyNTFS3G

Comment: Actually, it turns out it was a broken hard drive. Thanks for the help anyways. I got a new one and it installs fine.